# Why should the rows of $AB^\top$ sum to one if the rows of $A$ and column of $B$ sum to one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{b\times n}$
$$
\sum_j AB^\top = \mathbb{1}^a \quad \textit{iff} \quad \sum_jA = \mathbb{1}^a \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_i B = (\mathbb{1}^n)^\top
$$

I saw this immediately before section 3.4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01243.pdf) (they are using different notation). I tested this with random matrices and it is true, but I cannot see why this should always be true.

Is there some theorem or some easy reason to see why this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The rows of matrix $M$ sum to one" can be thought of as saying $M\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the all-ones vector. (If $M$ is not square, then these two $\mathbf 1$'s are of course different dimensions.) The $i^{\text{th}}$ entry of $M\mathbf 1$ is the dot product of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $M$ with $\mathbf 1$, which is just the sum of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $M$.

This is a very valuable kind of reframing: it often pays to restate a fact about matrices in terms of matrix multiplication whenever possible!

So you are given that the rows of $A$ sum to one (equivalently, $A\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$) and the columns of $B$ (the rows of $B^{\mathsf T}$) sum to one (equivalently, $B^{\mathsf T}\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$). With this information, we can simplify $AB^{\mathsf T}\mathbf 1$ to
$$
   A(B^{\mathsf T}\mathbf 1) = A \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1
$$
and conclude that the rows of $AB^{\mathsf T}$ also sum to one.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did not make the connection when you said "This is exactly what you need to simplify $AB^\top 1$ to $1$." Can you explain this point further?

Comment: Does my edit clarify matters?

Comment: yes, I see it now. Because $B^\top1 = 1$ therefore the whole expression $AB^\top1 = 1$